# Protractor runs into error, while trying to run on Chrome on Linux(Erro do Protractor ao tentar executar no Chrome no Linux)

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, protractor

Currently my `protractor.conf.js` code looks like: 
(Meu protractor.conf.js)

```js
// Protractor configuration file, see link for more information
// https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/lib/config.ts

const {
  SpecReporter
} = require('jasmine-spec-reporter');

exports.config = {
  allScriptsTimeout: 11000,
  specs: [
    './src/**/*.e2e-spec.ts' //Dentro de src ele vai ler e execulta todos arquivos com .e2e-spec.ts
  ],
  capabilities: {
    'browserName': 'chrome', //Qual Navegador usar
    //caso dê erro do Binário do Browser, coloca o caminho até o programa
    chromeOptions: {
      binary: '/usr/bin/google-chrome-stable'
    },
  },
  directConnect: true,
  baseUrl: 'http://localhost:4200/', //URL base que ele vai rodar
  framework: 'jasmine',
  jasmineNodeOpts: {
    showColors: true,
    defaultTimeoutInterval: 30000,
    print: function() {}
  },
  onPrepare() {
    require('ts-node').register({
      project: require('path').join(__dirname, './tsconfig.e2e.json')
    });
    jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(new SpecReporter({
      spec: {
        displayStacktrace: true
      }
    }));
  }
};
```

When I run `ng e2e`, to run the spec files, I run into the following errors "on Linux" (Quando rodo o ng e2e ele da esse erros "no Linux").
Any help on how to resolve or debug this?

[Terminal Response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aMbAr.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your configuration file,  make the following changes and give it a try :

```js
directConnect: true,
   capabilities: {
       'browserName': 'chrome',
        chromeOptions: {
             //args: [ "--headless", "--disable-gpu" ]

       },
   },
```

Remove the `baseUrl` field.

Comment: The error continues 
E/launcher - unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited abnormally
  (unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist)
  (The process started from chrome location /usr/bin/google-chrome is no longer running, so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed.)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.46.628388 (4a34a70827ac54148e092aafb70504c4ea7ae926),platform=Linux 4.19.0-6-amd64 x86_64)

Comment: E/launcher - WebDriverError: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited abnormally
  (unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist)
  (The process started from chrome location /usr/bin/google-chrome is no longer running, so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed.)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.46.628388 (4a34a70827ac54148e092aafb70504c4ea7ae926),platform=Linux 4.19.0-6-amd64 x86_64)